# Serial Downvoting Reversed with +4 bonus point

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, serial-voting

I was looking at a user's reputation tab https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437962/elyusubov?tab=reputation

There is a serial downvoting happened on 20th June date( total 28 downvote at 02:48 hours ). Have a look at the screenshot.

[image: Count for yourself.]

Now these downvotes are reversed with +60 points ( which should be 28 X 2 = 56 points ). So how come this +4 reputation awarded extra ? is it a bug while re-calculating the downvotes ?

Comment: You did thing about the possibility that the other 2 downvotes are from another day?

Comment: @UristMcBobby ,that user has only one previous downvote

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a deleted post that was downvoted as well and had that downvote reversed.

I've checked and verified that the actual reputation changes are correct. It basically went like this:

- user gets downvoted 30 times.
- votes get reversed.
- user removes one of the answers that had been downvoted (and "undownvoted" by the reversal script).
- things look weird.

Nothing to worry about here.

Comment: Pay no attention to the cat behind the curtain

Comment: Nice Analysis :)